# Self-organizing Fuzzy Neural Network (SOFNN) Implementations in Java, C, Python etc

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, neural-network, prediction

We are looking for an implementation of a Self-organizing Fuzzy Neural Network (SOFNN) in Java or another lang such as Python or C.

Looking at Neuroph, one of the best Neural Net frameworks out there for Java there is no such net type.

Is anyone aware of any working implementations of Fuzzy Neural Nets?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [NEFCLASS](http://fuzzy.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/nefclass/nefclass-j/)

Comment: Your answer is a *stub* and may eventually be deleted. Please provide [more substantive details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72002/141525) rather than just posting a link.

Comment: what more info is the OP looking for?  I haven't used it, so cannot comment directly, but it is pointing him directly towards an implementation in java he may find useful.  You can contribute useful information by posting an Answer.